# Omit values that are Option::None when encoding JSON with rustc_serialize

Tags: json, rust

I have a struct that I want to encode to JSON. This struct contains a field with type `Option<i32>`. Let's say

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json;

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct TestStruct {
    test: Option<i32>
}

fn main() {
    let object = TestStruct {
        test: None
    };

    let obj = json::encode(&object).unwrap();

    println!("{}", obj);
}
```

This will give me the output

```
{"test": null}
```

Is there a convenient way to omit `Option` fields with value `None`? In this case I would like to have the output

```
{}
```

Comment: `RustcEncodable` is not intended to cope with this sort of thing; it’s designed to have a fixed number of fields, though for something limited like JSON you could probably successfully cheat. It’d be asking for trouble, though. I would guess that [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) would handle this sort of thing, though I do not know for certain.

Comment: not yet, but there's an issue for that: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/43

Comment: you can always `impl Encodable` manually and make sure that serialization skips a `None` field

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll go with serde and wait for the issue to be resolved, because it's not that big of a deal and at the moment there are bigger issues. @ker I'll probably look later into implementing`Encodable` manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone arrives here with the same question like I did, serde has now an option skip_serializing_none to do exactly that.

https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.8.0/serde_with/attr.skip_serializing_none.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible by doing purely from a struct, so i converted the struct into a string, and then converted that into a JSON object. This method requires that all `Option` types be the same type. I'd recommend if you need to have variable types in the struct to turn them into string's first.

`field_vec` and `field_name_vec` have to be filled with all fields at compile time, as I couldn't find a way to get the field values, and field names without knowing them in rust at run time.

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

fn main() {


    #[derive(RustcEncodable)]
    struct TestStruct {
        test: Option<i32>
    }

    impl TestStruct {
        fn to_json(&self) -> String {
            let mut json_string = String::new();
            json_string.push('{');

            let field_vec = vec![self.test];
            let field_name_vec = vec![stringify!(self.test)];
            let mut previous_field = false;
            let mut count = 0;
            for field in field_vec {
                if previous_field {
                    json_string.push(',');
                }
                match field {
                    Some(value) => {
                        let opt_name = field_name_vec[count].split(". ").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1];
                        json_string.push('"');
                        json_string.push_str(opt_name);
                        json_string.push('"');
                        json_string.push(':');
                        json_string.push_str(&value.to_string());
                        previous_field = true;
                    },
                    None => {},
                }
                count += 1;
            }
            json_string.push('}');
            json_string
        }
    }

    let object = TestStruct {
        test: None
    };

    let object2 = TestStruct {
        test: Some(42)
    };

    let obj = Json::from_str(&object.to_json()).unwrap();
    let obj2 = Json::from_str(&object2.to_json()).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", obj);
    println!("{:?}", obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To omit `Option<T>` fields, you can create an implementation of the `Encodable` trait (instead of using `#[derive(RustcEncodable)]`).

Here I updated your example to do this.

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json::{ToJson, Json};
use rustc_serialize::{Encodable,json};

use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[derive(PartialEq, RustcDecodable)]
struct TestStruct {
    test: Option<i32>
}

impl Encodable for TestStruct {
    fn encode<S: rustc_serialize::Encoder>(&self, s: &mut S) -> Result<(), S::Error> {
        self.to_json().encode(s)
    }
}

impl ToJson for TestStruct {
    fn to_json(&self) -> Json {
        let mut d = BTreeMap::new();
        match self.test {
            Some(value) => { d.insert("test".to_string(), value.to_json()); },
            None => {},
        }
        Json::Object(d)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let object = TestStruct {
        test: None
    };

    let obj = json::encode(&object).unwrap();

    println!("{}", obj);

    let decoded: TestStruct = json::decode(&obj).unwrap();
    assert!(decoded==object);
}
```

It would be nice to implement a custom `#[derive]` macro which does this automatically for `Option` fields, as this would eliminate the need for such custom implementations of `Encodable`.